# Threads in Windows Service and lack of Ram Memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool

I'm making the windows service to get Account Information From Bank; My Service works well, but After some days(8 or more days) it uses more than 7 Gigabytes of RAM.(With 6 or 7 Threads);

Here is my Code:

```
private Thread MainThread;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(() => ConfigurationService());
                MainThread = new Thread(starter);
                MainThread.Start();
                // Event Started
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            MainThread.Abort();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Aborted", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
```

And Here is My Method Which Decides Which Day(s) information must receive;

```
private void ConfigurationService()
{
    serv = new ServiceSoapClient();
    serv.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse(@"2012/05/20");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            double days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Days;
            if (days > 30)
            {
                GetDataFromBank(startTime, startTime.AddDays(30)); 
                startTime = startTime.AddDays(31);
            }
            else
            {
                GetDataFromBank(startTime, startTime.AddDays(days));
                startTime = startTime.AddDays(days);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

And Here is The Main Method (Thread to Receive Data from Bank) :

```
private void GetDataFromBank(DateTime fromDT, DateTime toDT)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (fromDT > toDT)
                    break;
                try
                {
                   // Call The Bank Service
                   // Receive Transaction related to Specified Date
                   // Compare with Database if not Exist Add To Database
                    }
                }
                fromDT = fromDT.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ee.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }));
}
```

The service Works well and Receive All Information from StartDate untill EndDate;
after almost 1 hour the service just Check the CurrentDay every minutes and in TaskManager i  see 5 or 6 Active Thread and Memory usage Equal 24 Megabytes;

**Question :** Why Does The Service use more than 7 Gigabytes of RAM after some days?

Thanks in advance

Edit ===========

I forgot telling you I never turn off the Computer.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Garbage Collection to me. Maybe you are attaching eventhandlers that aren't released properly or you are keeping references to some objects, so that they aren't collected. You should consider doing some profiling, to see what occupies the memory.

Comment: Is there a need to always have the SoapServiceClient around? I would suggest creating it when you need it then cleaning it up instead of keeping it around like that.

Comment: Oh that error handling is so horrible. Maybe there are failures all the time causing tasks to queue up to no end and you'll never know because you suppress all errors.

Comment: @P_G ; you suggest me to call and have **SoapServiceClient**, only in **ThreadPool**? instead of global reference;

Comment: @usr ; I handle the errors and show them in EventViewer; the only Error I maybe get sometimes; is due to Timeout; and I handle it in Thread; something like this;

Comment: @usr ; I have this code inside of My Thread :  **PayRollResponse res = null;
try
{
res = serv.PayRollRequest(Accountnumber, fromDT, "username", "password");
}
catch
{
serv = new ServiceSoapClient();
serv.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = serv.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                            continue;
                        }**

Answer (score 3):

It surely is GC not being able to collect memory variable related to List or some collection variable where you keep stuffing data infinitely and that memory variable never goes out of reference. 
Since you are using infinite loop with while(true) watch out for collection variable you are using in that loop. See if it goes on increasing and increasing....

Are you using EF or some ORM ? If so, check whether you are always adding an entry to EF global context?

Comment: @Peter Ritchie, excuse me for my poor english!!! you meant probably GC did't get trigger,right?

Comment: Hi; Thanks for your Reply; I'm using EF which I Defined on the top of class like this : **private RefahDBEntities context** ; and have something like this in OnConfigurationService : **context = new RefahDBEntities();** ; So is this My Problem??

Comment: How often are you doing DB operation(add,fetch..) in that context. If you are enabling object tracking (by default tracking is enabled) in EF, then over time the size of you context grows if it is global to the class and you you create the context only once.If so try recreating an new context every now and then or disable object tracking if you don't require it.